# Sending non-RFC compliant HTTP request in browser

Tags: java, silverlight, http, plugins, browser

I need to send a non-RFC compliant HTTP request in a browser. I need to send a GET request without encoding the URL. I don't want whitespace to be encoded as %20. I know browsers shouldn't send such requests, but that's what I exactly need for my project.

I thought of using following ideas:

1. XHR - performs URL-encoding automatically and there is no way to manipulate it.
2. Java/Silverlight applet - opening the URL in a new browser tab doesn't allow for passing unencoded URL. As far as I know, applets just pass URL address to the browser and it's the browser that opens it.
3. Java/Silverlight applet - sending raw HTTP request and trying to display the results in a browser tab. Is it possible? If so, will the response be treated by the browser as a valid origin-sourced server response? I need to have access to the DOM with included (in the server response) scripts, so it can't break SOP.

Sample request:
    GET resource abc HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com

Comment: You knew this question was coming, but... why do you need a request that breaks convention?

Comment: Post a sample request string.

Comment: @corsiKa, I just knew someone will insist on knowing the answer ;). The answer is: cross-site scripting. I need it in order to exploit the vulnerability. It's done legitimately of course.

Answer (score 0):

In an HTTP header, it looks like
GET http://www.stackoverflow.com/ HTTP1.1

If you don't escape spaces in the URL, it will break the HTTP header.  No HTTP compliant server will be able to understand the request.

However, if you do have a legitimate reason to do this, you can just write the data to a socket and send it to the server.  See Java Sockets on Oracle's tutorials for more.

Comment: The server I tested understands the malformed request (I added sample in my initial post) and threats the 'abc HTTP/1.1' part as a HTTP version variable. I'm ok with that. Concerning your suggestion - if I use socket and send the data to the server I can't display the response in a browser. I need the browser to think the response originated from the server in order to have access to the DOM with scripts included in the response.

Comment: @user2498474 Why don't you pipe the result of the output to a .html file and open it with your browser?

Comment: @corsiKa It won't work as intended. User shouldn't be forced to create any file and open any files, but what's more important is the fact that opening HTML will not allow for access to the DOM of origin server responses (SOP forbids such access).

Comment: Just use Java to send the data back to a browser over a socket.

Comment: @SamSmith It won't allow for access to the DOM.